# The questions/ answer vote up are too close to the same color

Tags: bug, moderator-tools, design

I was looking at some of the plots in the Moderator Tools Analytics today, and I noticed that I was having a really hard time telling the difference between question up votes and answer up votes. They are both a green color, and while I was eventually able to tell the difference, it would be nice if there was a larger differential between them, especially since the number of votes often appears to be similar between the two. I can tell them apart, but it took me looking at it for a minute to tell the difference.

I should state, I saw this on Space Stack Exchange, which is in Beta. I'm not sure if it applies to all graduated sites. On Science Fiction, the difference appears to be slightly greater, this might be an effect of the background color, or that the lines are just more separated in general.

[image]

Comment: To make it consistent, question green should be on the blue side, and answer green on the yellow side. I suggest something like #00ffff and #88ff00.